# get data from http port to database

Tags: php, mysql, linux, database, python-requests

I'm currently trying to show the data I receive from my sensors on a webpage.

The data is transmitted via a GSM-module and from there I can either publish it or send it to an IP-Adress. For either option, I require a script to transfer the data from the http port to my Mysql-Database.

The problem is that I am new on this topic and I couldn't find a fitting manual or tutorial to td it by myself so I decided to ask this community for help!

The website and the database are running on a linux server

Has anyone here an idea if there is an easier or better way to get the data into the database or does some know where I can find a tutorial which explains the script I'd need?

Comment: Show your code that gets the data from the sensors, and the code you have to display and save the data.

Comment: You are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [doing more research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) 
if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and 
provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). 
Read [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). 
Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: Storing data in MySQL with PHP is literally PHP/MySQL 101 and there are literally thousands of [tutorials](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html). Perhaps taking a few online lessons at someplace like codecademy.com will get your started.